# Stored procedure if record exists then update

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to check if a record exists and then update it if it does

Here is what I current have: (Which obviously does not work)

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.update_customer_m
       @customer_id             INT                      , 
       @firstname               VARCHAR(30)          , 
       @surname                 VARCHAR(30)              , 
       @gender                  VARCHAR(6)               , 
       @age                     INT                  , 
       @address_1               VARCHAR(50)      , 
       @address_2               VARCHAR(50)              ,
       @city            VARCHAR(50)              ,
       @phone           VARCHAR(10)              ,
       @mobile          VARCHAR(11)              ,
       @email           VARCHAR(30)              ,               
AS 
    IF EXISTS 
    (
       SELECT *
       FROM dbo.Customer
       WHERE CustID = @customer_id
    )
BEGIN 
       UPDATE dbo.Customer
           SET Firstname = @firstname,  Surname = @surname, Age = @age, Gender = @gender, Address1 = @address_1, Address2 = @address_2, City = @city, Phone = @phone, Mobile = @mobile, Email = @email
       WHERE CustID = @customer_id
END
```

Is there a better way of doing this that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why both checking first?  The update will update no rows if the row doesn't exist:

```
   UPDATE dbo.Customer
       SET Firstname = @firstname,  Surname = @surname, Age = @age, Gender = @gender,
           Address1 = @address_1, Address2 = @address_2, City = @city,
           Phone = @phone, Mobile = @mobile, Email = @email
       WHERE CustID = @customer_id;
```

The `if` is not needed.

Comment: Although this works, My code is wrong, so I'll be opening up a new question. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if block not needed, first select if has no row, Update block do nothing and no row is affected.

just write your update in this procedure.

but maybe you want to write else if for this procedure, if it's OK, you can you IF and ELSE.
in IF block you can write this Update, and in ELSE block you can do another that want.

Comment: To help improve the clarify of your answer, please provide some code snippet. Also keep in mind that proper application of punctuation and correct grammar will help your readers to better understand your intent http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
   FROM dbo.Customer
   WHERE CustID = @customer_id
//add this
IF @@ROWCOUNT>=1
BEGIN 
   UPDATE dbo.Customer
       SET Firstname = @firstname,  Surname = @surname, Age = @age, Gender = @gender, Address1 = @address_1, Address2 = @address_2, City = @city, Phone = @phone, Mobile = @mobile, Email = @email
   WHERE CustID = @customer_id
END
```

Comment: I forgot to note to remove the if and else.